# What is the difference between ManagedExecutorService and ExecutorService in java

Tags: java, concurrency

I have a requirement of submitting task to executor service in my wildfly java ee application.

The current code is as below,

`ExecutorService jobExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();`
`jobExecutorService.submit(new Task(request));`

On each request, the same piece of code will run and submit the task for single-threaded executor.

But I am not sure whether the newly constructed thread is managed or is it a correct way of submitting tasks in my java ee application for any async flow.

If I need to start a thread which should be managed by the container, do I need to use ManagedExecutorService or is there any other implementation.

Need some knowledge on this.

Comment: The title has `ManagedExecutorService`, but not the question body. Did you miss a part?

Answer (score 6):

To answer the question out of the title:

`ManagedExecutorService` is part of the [Java EE specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedExecutorService.html) while `ExecutorService` is part of the [Java SE specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html).

The main difference between these two interfaces is that the `ManagedExecutorService` is just a

> manageable version of a ExecutorService.

Since you should not spawn any unmanaged Thread in an Java EE environment, you should only use the managed stuff there, while the unmanaged is perfectly fine for Java SE applications.

The proper way to get a `ManagedExecutorService` in a Java EE application is to inject the `ManagedExecutorService` with the `@Resource` annotation

```
@Resource
ManagedExecutorService managedExecutorService;
```

Comment: Hi @maio290, Do usage of ExecutorService in Java EE application leads to the creation of unmanaged threads?.

Comment: Well, I'd guess so.

Comment: @srinivas Yes it does !

Comment: I have seen Java EE application using ExecutorService for async execution. So it is not correct approach?

Comment: Yes, it's not the "correct" approach in an EE environment because it ditches the server's thread-management. However, this may only have an impact on systems with a high load, as long as the threads aren't leaking any resources. Thus I'd consider the impact neglectable in many cases, but since it's easy to refactor, it shouldn't be much of an issue for anyone.

Answer (score 4):

ExecutorService does n't need any web container, where as ManagedExecutorService is used in the context of application deployed to a webserver, where threadpools are created and their life cycles are maintained by the container.